# Python reversing an UTF-8 string

Tags: python, string, utf-8, character, reverse

I'm currently learning Python and as a Slovenian I often use UTF-8 characters to test my programs. Normally everything works fine, but there is one catch that I can't overtake. Even though I've got encoding declared on the top of the file it fails when I try to reverse a string containing special characters

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

a = "čšž"
print a    #prints čšž
b = a[::-1]
print b    #prints �šō� instead of žšč
```

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python 2 strings are *byte strings*, and UTF-8 encoded text uses multiple bytes per character. Just because your terminal manages to interpret the UTF-8 bytes as characters, doesn't mean that Python knows about what bytes form one UTF-8 character.

Your bytestring consists of 6 bytes, every two bytes form one character:

```
>>> a = "čšž"
>>> a
'\xc4\x8d\xc5\xa1\xc5\xbe'
```

However, how many bytes UTF-8 uses depends on where in the Unicode standard the character is defined; ASCII characters (the first 128 characters in the Unicode standard) only need 1 byte each, and many emoji need 4 bytes!

In UTF-8 order is *everything*; reversing the above bytestring reverses the bytes, resulting in some gibberish as far as the UTF-8 standard is concerned, but the middle 4 bytes just *happen* to be valid UTF-8 sequences (for `š` and `ō`):

```
>>> a[::-1]
'\xbe\xc5\xa1\xc5\x8d\xc4'
-----~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^####
  |     š       ō      |
  \                    \
   invalid UTF8 byte    opening UTF-8 byte missing a second byte
```

You'd have to decode the byte string to a `unicode` object, which consists of single characters. Reversing that object gives you the right results:

```
b = a.decode('utf8')[::-1]
print b
```

You can always *encode* the object back to UTF-8 again:

```
b = a.decode('utf8')[::-1].encode('utf8')
```

Note that in Unicode, you can still run into issues when reversing text, when [*combining characters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) are used. Reversing text with combining characters places those combining characters in front rather than after the character they combine with, so they'll combine with the wrong character instead:

```
>>> print u'e\u0301a'
éa
>>> print u'e\u0301a'[::-1]
áe
```

You can mostly avoid this by converting the Unicode data to its normalised form (which replaces combinations with 1-codepoint forms) but there are plenty of other exotic Unicode characters that don't play well with string reversals.

Comment: Just to clarify: _"but there are plenty of other exotic Unicode characters that don't interact with string reversals"_ means _"don't work well with string reversals"_ or _"are not affected by string reversals"_?

Comment: @Piovezan: I'm not 100% sure myself; I'm going with *don't play well with string reversals*.